# It is possible to verify that edge marketplace container image exists?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Everything is exposed via a REST API to publish new edge modules but a nice to have is on publishing we verify the given Docker container URL actually exists. This is to prevent having to publish, test a deployment, check Edge can pull the image, rinse and repeat until working (thinking is to make this idiot proof!). We have achieved this for our own registry and the mcr.micosoft.com (where edgeAgent/Hub live) with: “HEAD: https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/ azureiotedge-agent/manifests/1.0.8.5”.

However, when trying this on marketplace.azurecr.io (where SQL DB Edge lives) we get an 'unauthorised' response. I have also tried: “https://marketplace.azurecr.io/v2/azure-sql-database-edge/tags/list” but also unauthorised. I am able to pull the container image down with Docker Desktop which seeing as that requires to download the manifest first I am not sure what I can do to simply check the image exists. Do you know a way we could verify the image exists on this container registry?

Comment: Why don't you pull it locally first and push it to your private registry. Then reference the private registry in your deployment.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that is the plan B! :)